# onDragEnter and onDragLeave triggered again if a child is added. This doesn't happen with onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave

Tags: reactjs

If after a onDragEnter (and before leaving) a child is added to the element (containing the listener) that appears under the pointer a onDragLeave is triggered.
This doesn't happen with the mouse events.

The blue square listen to mouse events and the green one to drag events.
When dragging the red square (to the green one) and if the mouse is where the child is added the events are repeatedly triggered.

Is there a way to make drag events behave like mouse events?

TIA

PS:Stack Snippet doesn't seam to work with reactjs so here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ruifortes/gvLr0z39/

```js
var Placeholder = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<div className='placeholder'/>);
  }
})

var Draggable = React.createClass({
  dragStart: function(e){
     console.log("dragStart...") 
     
     //need to setData for firefox to work
     e.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", null) 
     
     this.setState({overed:true});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<div data-id="123" key="123" className='draggable'
                 draggable="true"
                 onDragStart={this.dragStart}>
             </div>);
  }
})

var SomeBox1 = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {overed: false};
  },
  dragEnter: function(e){
     console.log("dragEnter...");
     e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();
     this.setState({overed:true});
  },
  dragLeave: function(e){
     console.log("dragLeave...");
     e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();
     this.setState({overed:false});
  },  
  render: function() {
    console.log("render...");
    return (
      <div onDragEnter={this.dragEnter} onDragLeave={this.dragLeave}>
        {this.state.overed && <Placeholder/>}
      </div>
    );
  },
});

var SomeBox2 = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {overed: false};
  },
  mouseEnter: function(e){
     console.log("mouseEntered...")
     this.setState({overed:true})
  },
  mouseLeave: function(e){
     console.log("mouseLeave...")
     this.setState({overed:false})
  },  
  render: function() {
    console.log("render...")
    return (
      <div onMouseEnter={this.mouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.mouseLeave}>
        {this.state.overed && <Placeholder/>}
      </div>
    );
  },
});


React.renderComponent(<SomeBox1/>, document.getElementById('div1'));
React.renderComponent(<SomeBox2/>, document.getElementById('div2'));
React.renderComponent(<Draggable/>, document.getElementById('div3'));
```

```css
#div1 {
    width:50%;height:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
}
#div2 {
    width:50%;height:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
}
#div1 > div,#div2 > div {
    height:100%;
}
.placeholder {
  height: 50px;
  background: rgb(255,240,120);
}
.draggable {
  height: 30px; width:30px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.12.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.0.js"></script>

<div id="div1"></div><div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"/>
```

Comment: Ok...setting the CSS property "pointer-events: none;" disables an element from triggering mouse events. The question now is that I need to catch the "onDragDrop" event